# Secure cookies and Path Length Constraint

Tags: apache, cookies, setcookie

Using apache 2.2.3 on oracle enterprise linux.

When setting following setting in httpd.conf: **Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure** , cookie generation (which happens on our registration page) stops.

In certificate we have "Path Length Constraint=None" set. Its a L1C entrust cert. Can it be cause of it ?

Comment: Maybe `mod_headers` isn't installed?